# j2me problem with playing multiple sound files

Tags: java-me, audio-player, midp-2.0

I have a problem with playing more than 2 sound files in a game I'm developing now in j2me MIDP2 in eclipse.
Please advice me the best way for playing multiple "wav" sound files.
I created the following method that is called once when the program starts

```
public void setSound()
        {
            System.out.println("Sound on");
            try {
                p1=Manager.createPlayer(is1, "audio/X-wav");
                p2=Manager.createPlayer(is2, "audio/X-wav");
                p3=Manager.createPlayer(is3, "audio/X-wav");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MediaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and every time I need to play one of the sounds I stop the two other players (to insure that no one of them is running `p2.stop(); p3.stop();`) and start the third one (`p1.start();`) and every time I have two players stopped (being in PREFETCHED State) the third one is not running and exceptions are thrown.

Comment: can you show is1 and is3 ? and stacktrace

Comment: About stacktrace there is a little problem - DeBug doesn't work good on my eclipse, but their state returned by getState() is 300 prefetched. May be some problems with s40 limitation?

Comment: no need to debug just run your app,`e.printStackTrace();` must printed on your console if exception is thrown, and catch general `Exception` at last

Comment: Thanks, will run it and copy.

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J: Sir, your Caps Lock key seems to be malfunctioning. Please contact a technician.

Answer (score 1):

The Java ME spec is not specific about this, but on actual devices you can usually have only one *allocated* player at a time, so just stopping a player is not enough.  See also [this forum post](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_handle_multiple_sounds_in_Java_ME). I found it is a challenge even to deallocate a player properly before playing a new one, so [in my own code](http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/JGame/src-midp/jgame/platform/JGEngine.java) I resorted to waiting for one sound to end before trying to play a new one.

Answer (score -1):

in j2me there is only one player.More than 1 players are not supported.How execute the sound one sound after another or any other.If u want playing multiple sounds means then u follow the below coding

```
public class AudioPlayer implements javax.microedition.media.PlayerListener{

Player player;
int count=0;

public void playMedia(){

try{

player = Manager.createPlayer(getClass().getResourceAsStream(audioFiles[count]),"audio/x-amr");
player.addPlayerListener(this);
player.start();

}
catch (Exception e) {
return ;
}
}


public void playerUpdate(Player p,String event,Object eventData) 
{

        //Playing next audio file after completion of current audio.
}

}
```